# Commands not working inside shell script but working directly on the console

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, pm2

So i have this command which i want to run inside the script:

```
pm2 restart my-application --update-env
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u deploy bash << EOF
cd /home/deploy/my-agent
pm2 start ecosystem.json
EOF
echo "out of the deploy user"

echo "export edgeboxId=$edgeboxId">> /etc/bash.bashrc

sudo -u edgebox bash << EOF
pm2 restart my-application --update-env 
EOF
echo "out of application user"
sleep infinity
```

this command `pm2 restart my-application --update-env` doesnt work inside the script as expected(it should the update the env for pm2 but it restarts application without updating the env). Also it doesnt throw any error. The output of the command is:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [my-application](ids: [ 0 ])

[PM2] [my-application](0) ✓

┌─────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ my-application    │ default     │ 1.0.328 │ fork    │ 348      │ 0s     │ 2    │ online    │ 0%       │ 20.9mb   │ edgebox  │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But when i run this command directly on the console, it works as expected. So my question is, how to make this command work from inside script? It looks like some shell problem but i cant figure out.

**Note:** This command and the script is being run inside a docker container and the shell inside docker container is `/bin/bash` and version is `5.0.3(1)-release`.

Comment: What does it mean, that the command _does not work_? What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say? What is the exit code from the command?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I don't see in your update, what exit code you get. Also, the `>> /etc/bash.bashrc` is conspicuous. I would have expected that you don't have write permission for this file. I would do a `cat /etc/bash.bashrc` afterwards to verify this.

Comment: there is no exit code because the last command is `sleep forever` !? I can see my changes in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Also, I would do start the command by `sudo -u edgebox bash -x << EOF; ....`, which would guarantee you to show at least **something** on stderr and may help you finding the problem.

Comment: I meen the exit code of `pm2` of course!

Comment: i dont know what do you mean by exit code of pm2. I  again  updated the question with complete output of my pm2 command with `-x` flag you mentioned

Comment: Do immediately after a the pm2 a `echo pm2 exit code: $?`.  If you use `-x` as I suggested, you would also see the exit code of each statement automatically, and there is no need to do the `echo`. BTW, where is the generated file `bash.bashrc` being processed? This is not a standard startup file of _bash_, so there must be somewhere a command, which sources the content of this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch `pm2` because its location is part of the `$PATH` variable. That `$PATH` variable is user dependent.
So, when you do `sudo` you switch to another user, which means another `$PATH` variable, so it's possible that `pm2`'s location is not there.

In order to solve this, switch to that user in command prompt and adapt `$PATH` environment variable (in a persistent way).

Comment: Both root and edgebox user is using the same pm2. I checked pm2 path using command `which pm2` and for both users the command output is `/usr/local/bin/pm2`

Comment: In this case, the OP would have got an error message, but he explicitly said that there is no message.

Comment: @Anudocs: For checking the validity of a command, `which` is a poor choice, because it would not show if a function of the same name hides the command. A better choice would be `type -a pm2`. Further, please update your question so that we can see, where exactly you have put your debugging commands, so that we can see that you have put them in a reasonable place.